# How to split mail according to both "from" and "subject"?

Tags: gnus

Hope to try to filter some mail `from` "foo@example.com" and the `subject` contains "sw-report".

I tried to put this configure to my init.el:

```
   (setq nnmail-split-methods 'nnmail-split-fancy
         nnmail-split-fancy
         '(any "sw-report"
               (from "foo@example.com" "nnmaildir+COMPANY:INBOX.SWREPORT")))
```

But it doesn't work. Nothing is filtered.

My inbox is locate at `nnmaildir+COMPANY:INBOX`.

Answer (score 1):

`nnimap-split-fancy` is actually a server variable rather than a global variable, so the right place to set it is as part of `gnus-secondary-select-methods`. So something like this:

```
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnimap
        "Work"
        (nnimap-user "bob@example.com")
        ;; Other server vars
        (nnimap-split-fancy
         (| (any "sw-report"
                 (from "foo@example.com" "INBOX.SWREPORT"))
            ;; other rules
            )))))
```

(This is untested, and I always have trouble with splitting syntax, so it will probably require tweaking before it works.)